# SQLite: how to fill new column with values?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to create a new column called `index` in my table and insert rows with values from 1 to 100.

```
index
-----
1
-----
2
-----
3
-----
-
-
-
-
100
-----
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

EXCEPT:

```
for (i 1 to 100){
    insert(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to use a function. Because sqlite does not support user functions you need to write one in your application. That means the easiest way to realize what you want is to build up a insert SQL statement through a loop and execute it.